# How can I make Google Sheets tell me how many of each date are in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a column in my spreadsheet that contains only Date values, like:

```
2014-05-17
2014-06-19
2014-07-16
2014-07-16
2014-07-21
2014-07-21
2014-07-21
2014-07-21
2014-07-21
2014-06-17
2014-06-24
2014-06-24
2014-07-18
2014-07-21
2014-07-21
2014-06-13
2014-06-17
```

**How do I have Google Sheets give me, say, a line chart depicting how many of each date are in the column**, like:

[image: A chart representation of the above data]

If the above dates were the only ones I was working with, this wouldn't be a problem. However, there are up to 20 new dates added every day, and none removed. I want this to happen as automatically as possible, without having to add a new cell or update a formula every day.

Comment: @pnuts either skip it or 0

Comment: New data is added to the column multiple times daily. I want something that will not have to be rewritten and will just display and update this chart every time one is added

Comment: I made an edit that might help

Answer (score 3):

You can reproduce the required table using a formula (this will only work on the newest version of Sheets):

`=QUERY({A:A,A:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', count(Col2) 'Number'",0)`

And then reference that output for your graph.

If you are on the old version:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,1},A:A),"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', count(Col2) 'Number'",0))`

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNCol2`

Comment: Apologies for missing this... are you on the new or old version of Sheets? (green check mark icon at the bottom right)

Comment: the new one, shiny new material-designed sheets-only browser and all

Comment: Hmmm, and the first formula is the exact one you have used? Just tested it again and seems to work. If you have adapted it for you spreadsheet, perhaps copy and paste the exact formula you have used.

Comment: When I copy/paste yours exactly, I get `Error: Circular dependency detected.` So I used `=QUERY({List!E:E,A3:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', count(Col2) 'Number'",0)` since I'm drawing from another sheet with data in another column and don't want this cell overridden.

Comment: I think you will need `=QUERY({List!E:E,List!E:E},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', count(Col2) 'Number'",0)`

Comment: Why `List!E:E,List!E:E`? I don't like how you don't explain your solution at all.

Comment: You are creating a two-column table which allows you to perform the QUERY. Enter ={List!E:E,List! E:E} into a spare cell of another sheet to see what it does. And enter the embedded array that you attempted to use to compare.

Comment: Where will this two-column table go? I don't want it overriding my data. Also, what's an "embedded array"?

Comment: The table can go wherever you please. You could create a new sheet, name it 'Charting Data', and enter it there. You could hide that sheet if you wish. An embedded array is an array created in a formula with curly braces. Another example of an embedded array is ={1;2;3} (try entering that somewhere to see what it does; you only need 3 spare cells for that).

Comment: I suppose a better way to word my question is "What controls where the table will go?"

Comment: Forgive me if I have misunderstood your question, but the table will go wherever you enter the formula. That is, if the formula is entered in A1 of some sheet, the top-left cell of the table output will be in A1 of that sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Put a column labels at the top of the column

Put in a helper column next to it, and in every cell say

=if(ISBLANK(A1),0,1)

Then choose Data > Pivot Table Report, and enter the data range as A:B

This will create a new tab with the data series you want.   You can then create a graph from this.

See an example of this approach here:    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UIa4x1A2EWfTJUFUJbM3QkOzp-sHY12w9d7tprVPfDU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In all 65,536+ rows?

Comment: You need to put the formula in as many rows as you think may realistically by used.    Up to 65,536 if you expect that much data - but if you do, you really should be building a solution in a robust database that's scaled for the problem at hand, not using a spreadsheet!

Comment: But I'm just trying to track which companies I've applied to and when! Currently, there are nearly 100, but I don't wanna put an explicit limit on it

Comment: Just put it in as many rows as you might realistically every have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for a helper column:

[image: WA65591 example]

The data range for the chart is considerably more rows than shown as in use - and the same goes for the pivot table.